How to forget history in langchain
I think I may be fundamentally misunderstanding something with Langchain.
I want to evaluate and give feedback to student's simple answers to some Code based questions. If I run my code for one student then the evaluation is good and I get a reasonable grade and feedback. If I try the same with a number of students then the student with a low mark seems to get their mark elevated to match the other. It seems like if I run an isolated (one student) check then the score is good (I'm looking to give a score and feedback) but running over many students seems to influence the overall score/grade for all students. How do I run my checks over many students with one student's work influencing another. I assumed removing chat-history and chroma DB would do that. But no.
Here's a section of my code with a loop over answers. Each answer is the student's answer and some other information in the dict. I've moved everything into the loop i.e. creating new model object, prompty and chromaDB but something is still influencing grade??
answer['answer'] is actually a string of Java code e.g. a simple class or unit test, answer to a specific question. The students will have similar answers (I would hope)
Am just using the wrong model or am I missing something more fundamental?
code is below
Thanks
Jason

    for answer in answers:


        model = ChatOpenAI(api_key=api_key, model="gpt-4")
        if len(answer['answer']) > 200:
            java_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter.from_language(
                language=Language.JAVA, chunk_size=2000, chunk_overlap=200
            )
            texts = java_splitter.split_text(answer['answer'])
            db=Chroma(persist_directory="data/"+answer['username']).from_texts(texts, OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=open_ai_key, disallowed_special=()))

            retriever = db.as_retriever(
                search_type="mmr",  # Also test "similarity"
                search_kwargs={"k": 1},
            )

            prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
                [
                    (
                        "system",

                        "Answer the user's questions, Ensure the output is a well-formed Python dictionary, remember to escape single quotes and don't use brackets, based on the below context:\n\n{context}",
                    ),
                    ##("placeholder", "{chat_history}"),
                    ("user", "{input}"),
                ],

            ).partial(format_instructions=format_instructions)

            document_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(model, prompt)

            qa = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, document_chain)

            result = qa.invoke({"input": lecturer_question})

           

    print(responses)


Have you tried using ChromaDB without persisting the vector store in a directory?

@InsertCheesyLine Yes! Thanks. I thought I was not persisting the data. Deleted the docs and resolved.
